# Automatically smooth bevel faces on apply

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to automatically set Faces to "Smooth" that where created by applying the bevel modifier?

It's for exporting, so autosmooth is not an option.

Comment: If you are exporting using fbx format, there is an option to apply smoothing to faces as you export your file.

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I want to keep flat faces set to "Flat" and only set the face created by the bevel modifier to "Smooth" (in Edit mode)

Comment: or you can add an edge split modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found an easy way. Set a material for the bevel modifier, thankfully Blender keeps the material assignment after applying. So it's easy to select and set faces to smooth.

[image: Bevel Smooth]

Comment: Too bad that doesn't work unless you "apply".

Comment: Please read the original question.

Comment: Yes, I read it.  Too bad that won't work without "apply". :(